# Rename file while move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, upload, rename

Anyway, I got this code:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploaded/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Which just uploads my file, but I also got $newname, which gives it a new name, problem is, how do I actually rename it to $newname before/while it gets uploaded?

Answer (score 2):

You would rename it while you're moving it, so change:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploaded/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

to:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploaded/" . $newname);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to [move_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file) is the destination path, so simply use the `$newname` variable as a part of this.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploaded/" . $newname);
```

Incidentally, you should also use [is_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) to ensure that the source file is really an upload. (Likewise, you should ensure that `$newfile` is a safe filename for the operating system in use.)